# Extract rotation from matrix4d

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d

I get a a transformation matrix from some software, and i have to extract the axis rotation. I'm not sure of the exact name, but i would like to have the opposite function of Matrix4d.rotX(a).

Let's say i have this code :

```
Matrix4d matrix = new Matrix4d();
matrix.setIdentity();
Matrix4d m = new Matrix4d();
m.rotX(a);
matrix.mul(m);
m.rotY(b);
matrix.mul(m);
m.rotZ(c);
matrix.mul(m);
```

I would like to be able to get the value a, b and c from matrix. Would anyone have an idea ? I unforntunatly have almost no experience in 3D, I looked into the java vecmath package, but could not find anything.

I tried with the following :

```
 public static float[] getRotation(Matrix4f matrix) {
        float Yaw;
        float Pitch;
        float Roll;
        if (Math.abs(matrix.m00 + 1.0f) < 0.01f )
        {
            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(matrix.m02, matrix.m23);
            Pitch = 0;
            Roll = 0;

        }else if (Math.abs(matrix.m00 -1.0f) < 0.01f)
        {
            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(matrix.m02, matrix.m23);
            Pitch = 0;
            Roll = 0;
        }else
        {

            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(-matrix.m20,matrix.m00);
            Pitch = (float) Math.asin(matrix.m10);
            Roll = (float) Math.atan2(-matrix.m12,matrix.m11);
        }
        return new float[] { Yaw, Pitch, Roll};
    }
```

and

```
public static float[] GetRotation(Matrix4f matrix) {
        float Yaw;
        float Pitch;
        float Roll;
        if (matrix.m00 == 1.0f)
        {
            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(matrix.m20, matrix.m32);
            Pitch = 0;
            Roll = 0;

        }else if (matrix.m00 == -1.0f)
        {
            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(matrix.m20, matrix.m32);
            Pitch = 0;
            Roll = 0;
        }else
        {

            Yaw = (float) Math.atan2(-matrix.m02,matrix.m00);
            Pitch = (float) Math.asin(matrix.m01);
            Roll = (float) Math.atan2(-matrix.m21,matrix.m11);
        }
        return new float[] { Yaw, Pitch, Roll};
    }
```

but the value are wrong

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50963/how-to-extract-euler-angles-from-transformation-matrix

Comment: I already tried but can not make it work.

Comment: You haven't shared your code, so I can't offer any hints as to where it is incorrect.

Comment: i've edited and add the functions i tried.

Comment: " the value are wrong" is not a description of the problem. Please give your inputs, along with your expected and actual outputs.

Comment: My guess would be that you are decomposing `(a * b * c)`, whereas the code you are trying to use decomposes `(c * b * a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, here is the code to make it work:

```
    public static float[] getRotation(Matrix4f matrix) {
            float x,y,z;
            Matrix3f m = new Matrix3f();

            matrix.get(m);
            if(Math.abs(m.m02 - 1) < 0.0000001) {
                x = (float) Math.atan2(-m.m10,m.m11);
                y = (float) (-3.1415926535897931/2);
                z = 0.0f;
            } else if(Math.abs(m.m02 + 1)< 0.0000001) {
                x = (float) Math.atan2(m.m10,m.m11);
                y = (float) (3.1415926535897931/2);
                z = 0.0f;
            } else {
                x = (float) Math.atan2(m.m12,m.m22);
                y = (float) Math.atan2(-m.m02, Math.sqrt(m.m12 * m.m12 + m.m22 * m.m22));
                z = (float) Math.atan2(m.m01,m.m00);
            }

            return new float[] {x,y,z};
}
```

Comment: It's similar to this example: https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/blob/master/ardor3d-math/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/math/Matrix3.java#L1072 You treat the singularities on poles and then the general case. It's a non linear solution to work around the famous problem of gimbal lock. I hope that you understand this source code.